Unable to get non default method from the controller in ASP.NET Core 8 with Angular frontend
I am using ASP.NET Core 8.0 with Angular v17+ frontend. I can only get my default get method from the controller but not my other one.
My controller looks like this:
[Route("api/values")]
[ApiController]
public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
{
    // GET: api/<ValuesController>
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult<IEnumerable<string>> Get()
    {
        return Ok(new string[] { "ActionResult<IEnumerable<string>> Get()" });
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("getme")]
    public ActionResult<IEnumerable<string>> GetMe()
    {
        return Ok(new string[] { Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + " | " + Guid.NewGuid().ToString() });
    }
}

I can get the first method, but the second GET method I get a

Http failure during parsing for http://localhost:4200/api/values/getme

Not sure what I am doing wrong. I did test it using the full path and that works for some reason.
This is my proxy.config.json:
{
  "/api/*": {
    "target": "https://localhost:44351",
    "secure": false,
    "logLevel": "debug"
  }
}


@YongShun No it doesn't work. These methods work in swagger, but not in my frontend for some reason.

Weird thing is it works when I deploy

Check the network tab in the Browser console, what is the response returned from this API, possibly that it is not returning a JSON response.

@YongShun the response returned is html

Ya, that is why you get the error: "Http failure during parsing for", as the Angular HTTP Client is unable to extract/process it as JSON by default. So you need to further analyze what is the response content, do you need to send the dataType: 'json' as request header, and make sure you are returning the response JSON in your API.

@YongShun That doesn't explain why the first method works but when I add a route name in the controller it doesn't

After hours of trying to solve this. This is what I did to fix it
Original proxy.config.json
{
  "/api/*": {
    "target": "https://localhost:44351",
    "secure": false,
    "verbose": true
  }
}

Updated proxy.config.json
{
  "/api/**": {
    "target": "https://localhost:44351",
    "secure": false,
    "verbose": true
  }
}

Difference is that extra *

"/api/*" matches any request directly under /api/. For example, it
matches /api/values but not /api/values/getme.
"/api/"** matches any request under /api/ at any level of depth. For
example, it matches both /api/values and /api/values/getme.

Your welcome to ever else finds this useful.
